# Compare two CSV and export only a list of names that don't exist in both

Tags: powershell, csv, compareobject

I have 2 CSV files with user names.
I want to export just the names of users who don't exist in both files.

The code I have now:

```
$file1 = import-csv -Path "C:\ps\output\adusers.csv" 
$file2 = import-csv -Path "C:\ps\output\users.csv" 
Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -property name | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\ps\result\result.csv"
```

Comment: Looks like my exports are not correct. Thanks for all the answers will test it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Select-Object name` to extract only the name field from Compare-Object's output:

```
Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -Property name |
    select name |
    sort -unique -Property name |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\ps\result\result.csv"
```

Notes:

- `sort -unique` deduplicates and sorts the list.
- In case the CSV are huge, use [HashSet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39925896)

Comment: +1. A couple of the other answers here mention **SideIndicator** which isn't helpful when you want mismatched entries from _both_ input objects, but useful to be aware of in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to use `Compare-Object` for only the differences from *file1*:

```
$file1=import-csv "C:\temp\test\adusers.csv" 
$file2=import-csv "C:\temp\test\users.csv"

Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -Property "Name" | 
    Where SideIndicator -eq "<=" |
    Select Name | 
    Export-Csv "C:\temp\test\result.csv" -NoType
```

If you want all differences (from both files) remove this part:

```
'Where SideIndicator -eq "<=" |'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind [using linq/NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41989192/2746150), this will list users present in BOTH lists:

```
$file1 = import-csv -Path "C:\ps\output\adusers.csv" 
$file2 = import-csv -Path "C:\ps\output\users.csv" 
[linq.enumerable]::intersect( [object[]]($file1.name), [object[]]($file2.name) ) | 
  Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\ps\result\result.csv"
```

Linq does not have method opposite/reverse to intersect but you can use [SymmetricExceptWith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5620306/2746150) from generic collections.

Code below lists users who are present either in one list or another but not in both at once:

```
$file1 = import-csv -Path "C:\ps\output\adusers.csv" 
$file2 = import-csv -Path "C:\ps\output\users.csv" 
$res = [Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]]( [string[]]($file1.name) )
$res.SymmetricExceptWith( [string[]]($file2.name) )
$res | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\ps\result\result.csv"
```

Note: this code may not work on earlier powershell versions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SideIndicator to get the differences.

```
$file1 = import-csv -path C:\Output\Test.csv
$file2 = import-csv -path C:\Output\DomainUsers.csv
Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -property name -IncludeEqual | where-object {($_.SideIndicator -eq "=>") -or ($_.SideIndicator -eq "<=") } | Export-csv C:\Output\Difference.csv –NoTypeInformation
```

Note: You can use the *sort -unique* also in your case.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You use **-IncludeEqual** and then use the `Where-Object` cmdlet to ignore such cases (they cancel each other out). In effect this means the solution here isn't actually any different to the original example.

Comment: I tried it and its working properly. If you wish I can send the screenshot for the same @CharlieJoynt